# jQuery - Fadein only once

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$("#toolbar").hover(function () {
    $(".logo").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $(this).addClass("logohover")
        $(this).parent().addClass("logohover").fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(".logo").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });

});

<div id="toolbar">
 <div class="logo">
  &nbsp;
 </div>
</div>
```

When I hover over `#toolbar` it fades the .logo background out (Background is set in CSS), then changes the class to `.logohover` and fades it back in with a different background set in the CSS.

However when I then move the cursor off `#toolbar` and then hover back over the toolbar the `.hoverlogo` fade's in and out.

When the `<div>` is set to `.logohover` I dont want it to fade out on hover.

How can I adjust my jQuery to achive this? OR adjust my jQuery so I get a better effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the event handlers are still there and will react accordingly.

You could try adding a check in the event handler to check the element's class name and abort, i.e.:

```
if ($('.logo').hasClass('logohover')) return
```